# How to use Telnet from Java

Tags: java, sockets, runtime, exec, telnet

I need to telnet to a server, execute a few scripts, give inputs to those and receive output. 
Can I directly use Runtime.exec() and give the telnet command or do I need to learn about sockets?
I understand that in the exec() method, I might need to do the input and output in 2 threads, is that right?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither.  Use [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/), specifically the [Telnet support part](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/telnet/package-summary.html). No need to muck about with external processes, low-level socket handling or telnet command codes.

Comment: Thanks but what if we're not sure whether the user has that package or not? The program should work without any effort on the part of the user.

Comment: @rv1822: In that case, learn how to package additional JARs with your application. Limiting yourself to the JRE only is not a good idea.